# How to hide shadow of a dialog box in flutter?

Tags: flutter

My app has a user profile with a profile image. Clicking on this image should show a large version of it. I use the code below and it works nicely except the black shadow you can see around the image. It is OK that the background is darkened but I don't want the different colors at the borders.

```
  showProfileImage(url) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (_) => Dialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child:CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 150,
                  backgroundImage: Image.network(
                    url,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ).image)),
            )));
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Inside Dialog widget:

```
elevation: 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if there's a way to disable the shadow/overlay affect a dialog has? Basically so I can get a dialog looking like it does on the right side of this image:

[image]

My best attempt at this was to use a stack containing my custom dialog which are then toggled to be displayed or not but then I had trouble being able to scroll each custom dialog's own ListView without it messing up another. I know this goes against the Material Design guidelines but I'm trying to replicate a UI from dribble.com.

Thanks!

Edit:

I've managed to almost achieve this affect by editing the `showGeneralDialog` method but there's still an elevation shadow:

```
await showGeneralDialog(
    context: context,
    pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: Builder(builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
             content: Container(
                 color: Colors.white,
                 width: 150.0,
                 height: 150.0,
                 child: Center(child: Text("Testing"))));
        }),
      );
    },
    barrierDismissible: true,
    barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context)
        .modalBarrierDismissLabel,
    barrierColor: null,
    transitionDuration:
        const Duration(milliseconds: 150));
```

Edit 2: Just an image to illustrate the change on the above code showing that I've so far been able to disable the dark overlay but there's still elevation on the dialog which I can't seem to get rid of:

[image]

Edit 3: I think if I'm able to change the `AlertDialog` in the `showGeneralDialog`'s `Builder` then I can get it to work but I'm having trouble putting in something which is `Material` but doesn't take up the whole screen.

Comment: Any solution. I want to remove the shadow too?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Dialog Widget use Center Widget. I think it will solve the problem.

FYP : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html